# R: combine list of lists into a single dataframe

Tags: r

I have a list (res) containing p x b number of dataframes. Each dataframe has 12 columns but varying number of rows (e.g, `res[[1]][[1]]` has 12 cols and 36 rows, but `res[[1]][[1]]` has 12 cols and 38 rows).
I would like to combine them into a single dataframe that has 12 columns and 179 rows let's say. 
The`do.call("rbind", listOfDataFrames)` method doesn't work as I loose column and row information. Let me know, if further specification is needed.
Many thanks!

Comment: what about: `library(data.table);rbindlist(listOfDataFrames)`

Comment: it gives me the following error: `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  Invalid column: it has dimensions. Can't format it. If it's the result of data.table(table()), use as.data.table(table()) instead.`

Comment: can you post the result of `dput(listOfDataFrames)` ?

Comment: quite long, I guess I have to remove it from the question later on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact it is a list containing `5` elements. And the first element is a list of dataframes, whereas the other elements `2`, `3`, `4` and `5` are `NULL`. so you need to do access the first element of your list:

```
do.call(rbind, listOfDataFrames[[1]])
```

Or:

```
rbindlist(listOfDataFrames[[1]])
```

Comment: It is possible to do `lst = Filter(function(u) !is.null(u),listOfDataFrames)`

Comment: Thanks again! Just one more info here, maybe it will be important for those who will encounter a bit different problem. If you have a hierarchical list like `results[[p]][[b]]` and you want to combine this into one single dataframe, the solution is: `list <- unlist(results, recursive = FALSE) 
df<-rbindlist(list)` I just added this, maybe it will be useful for someone...